# Windows cannot find hcw

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am trying to migrate an old `MFC` project to `VS 2012` and one of the errors I get is this one:

[image]

From what I read is that it has something to do with `Help Files`, which are not supported on `Windows 7`.

I thought that maybe `Windows` is searching for the `hcw` path so I added to the `Environment Variables`, but I still get the error. From the code I can see that the command is called inside `.mak` files:

```
start /wait hcw /C /E /M "hlp\$(InputName).hpj"
```

Anyone has an idea how can I get rod of the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project requires Microsoft Help Workshop.

Comment: I have installed MHW but do I need to set this somewhere in the project ?

Comment: Just PATH. Try to specify a full path to hcw in mak file.

Comment: @KonstantinL And if we want to delete MHW from the build, how can we do that?

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into the same issue.  VS 6 project promoted to VS2013.

To eliminate the error. remove the Projectname.hpj file from the project.

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work. I still have the error

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem in the [post build step](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d399cb83-c686-4e23-8357-2d1c4863c940/hcw-file?forum=csharpide).