# Migration VC++ 06 to Visual Studio 2012 : remove hcw from the compilation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, chm, html-help

I'm migrating a VC++ 06 project to Visual Studio 2012.
I got an error when I compile.

[image]

```
1>  Copying contents file...
1>  the specified file is not found
1>  Making help include file...
1>  Making help file...
1>  The system cannot find the file hcw.
1>hlp\MyProject.hpj(1): error : 
1>  the specified file is not found
```

I removed the folder hlp (it got the .hpj file), the Makefile (.mak) but it still want to reach it.

Why? How can I build my project without HTML Help Project?

I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678965/windows-cannot-find-hcw) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

I edit the .dsp file (VC++ 6 Project) and remove the HTML Help lines declaration.
When I add an existing project from the .dsp, it automatically load that configuration. Even if I deleted the Makefile or the hlp folder.

Answer (score 1):

you should open the .dsw file with new version visual studio, before building the project, open the vxcproj and find the custom-build for help (search the "hjp" word)

delete this part from vxcproj and compile the Project.

Comment: search the "hpj" word